# No unity-2d folder in gconf-editor > desktop

Tags: unity-2d

I upgraded a Dell Inspiron E1505 from 10.04 to Natty (11.04) two days ago.  I wanted to change properties in my Unity toolbar but when I opened gconf-editor > desktop I found that there was no unity-2d folder.

What IS under gconf-editor < desktop is gnome, ibus and pgp.  What do I do now?

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, I did not find a `unity-2d` folder in my gconf either: ![missing folder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Onb2J.png) I tried your suggestion but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Unity 2D installed. You can check by running:

```
dpkg -l | grep "ii" | sed -e 's/^ii\ \ //g' -e 's/\ .*$//g'
```

If you have Unity 3D installed, it will return `unity` only. If you have Unity 2D installed, it will return `unity-2d`. If you have both installed, it will return both.

If `unity-2d` is installed and it still doesn't show up in `gconf-editor`, try running:

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
```

and then log out and log back in.